# PHP check password script wont work for more than one user

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a simple login credentials checker (with session variables).

this is what i have so far:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$u_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$p_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pword']);
# *** querying all records ***
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valid_username, valid_password FROM notes_users");
while($rst = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

//echo $rst[valid_username] . ", ";
//echo $u_name . " || ";
//echo ($rst[valid_username] == $u_name) . " || ";
//echo $rst[valid_password] . ", ";
//echo $p_word . " || ";
//echo ($rst[valid_password] == $p_word) . " || ";
//echo (($rst[valid_username] == $u_name) AND ($rst[valid_password] == $p_word));
//echo "<br/>";

if (($rst[valid_username] == $u_name) AND ($rst[valid_password] == $p_word)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
    header('Location: main.php') ;
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = '';
    header('Location: badlogin.php') ;
}


}

?>
```

here is the issue: If the MySQL table has more than one user in it's list, the check breaks. only the **last-entered user in the table** has access granted. anyone above the last user entered gets bumped to the incorrect login screen- even when the credentials are correct. why is this happening? can anyone suggest a code fix or better code to implement this login check?

edit: the comment code tests to see if the credentials supplied match those on record. that part of the script works fine.

problem solved! thank you all. for anyone who sees this in the future, definitely encrypt your passwords, mine are plain text because this is a local test application and wont even see an upload to the net.

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: query using the username. the database is optimised precisely for that sort of thing - use it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to loop through all your user records. Imagine if you would have a database with 1000000 users, you will only need to try fetching the record that corresponds to the supplied username and password. Update your query to something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes_users 
                      WHERE 
                      valid_password = '$p_word' && 
                      valid_username = '$u_name'");
```

Then you would do something like:

```
if (($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   // valid user
} else {
   // invalid password or username
}
```

Comment: technically he's looping through every record, and it's going to break unless his record he wants to authenticate is the last record. So he either needs to exit the loop when it's the username he wants to authenticate against in the db (bad idea) or be specific with the query (good idea).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, dont store password in plain-text form! Use md5/sha1 hash instead.

Second, this is not a good idea to get a list of all users in database. You WHERE Clause in SQL Queries - This will solve your problem as well..

Answer (score 0):

You should check the login details of a particular user.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valid_username, valid_password FROM notes_users WHERE valid_password = '$p_word' && valid_username = '$u_name' ");
```

which will return the only one row which is to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you querying for the user's credentials directly? For example:

```
$statement = mysql_query("SELECT valid_username FROM notes_users WHERE \
valid_username = '{$u_name}' and valid_password = '{$p_word}' LIMIT 1;");

if ( mysql_num_rows($statement) > 0 ) { /* log user in */ }
else { /* bad log in */
```

Oh, and why aren't you using the === operator for string comparison? Look into it, it's more practical.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad code,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valid_username, valid_password FROM notes_users");
```

use below code:

```
$postedUsername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']));
$postedPass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valid_username, valid_password FROM notes_users where username='$postedUsername' and password='$postedPass'");
```

Comment: I am new at stackoverflow.Ok,sorry. I will improve it.